# Windows 10 stalling print queue on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

When our Windows 10 devices print from Microsoft Edge the print hits the Window Server 2012 print queue, and just hangs at printing/spooling. This goes on until I manually clear the queue, and restart the print-spooler. As far as I have seen, the only program with printing issues is Edge.

Is this a driver issue? Where does one start fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected the driver was the culprit.

I updated the driver and waited for a good time to test. After swapping the driver on the print server there were no more problems and the queue has not stopped since!